# Android Bitmap Memory Issue - Error: Out of memory on a 8294416-byte allocation

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am currently developing an app that goes through a story.  The story contains "scenes" which contain multiple JPEG and PNG files that are displayed via ImageViews.  I create the ImageView and add at it to the layout via the following function:

```
private ImageView newImage(Show show)
{
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    String filePath = comin.generateFilePath(show);
    Log.i(TAG, "newImage, filePath = " + filePath + " id = " + show.id);
    WeakReference<Bitmap> bmp = new WeakReference<Bitmap>(scaleBitmap(filePath)); //added 4/1/13
    //Bitmap bmp = scaleBitmap(filePath);
    Log.i(TAG, "newImage, width = " + bmp.get().getWidth() + ", height = " + bmp.get().getHeight());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp.get());
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setId(show.id);

    //set visibility
    if (show.visible)
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //set dimensions
    int width = (app.getWidth() * show.dimX) / 100;
    int height = (app.getHeight() * show.dimY) / 100;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    iv.setLayoutParams(rlp);

    return iv;
}
```

Once the scene is over, I then clear all of the ImageViews except for one which has no image and only serves to listen for touch events.

```
private void clearScene(boolean clearTouch)
{
    RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    logMemory("clearScene, START");

    int count = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int a = count - 1; a >= 0; a--)
    {
        int id = parent.getChildAt(a).getId();
        String message = "clearScene id = " + id + ", count = " + count + ", a = " + a;
        if (id == TOUCH_VIEW_ID && !clearTouch)
        {
            message = message + ", ignore touch screen view";
        }
        else
        {
            unbindView(parent.getChildAt(a));
            parent.getChildAt(a).clearAnimation();
            parent.removeView(parent.getChildAt(a));
            message = message + ", unbindView, clearAnimation, removeView";
        }
        Log.i(TAG, message);
        logMemory("clearScene, CLEARED VIEW");
    }

    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);  //stop any future scheduled tasks from triggering
    logMemory("clearScene, BEFORE TRASH COLLECTOR");
    System.gc();
    logMemory("clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR");
}
```

As you can see, I call the unbindView() method, to try and clear any type of possible memory leak.

```
private void unbindView(View view)
{
    String message = "unbindView, id = " + view.getId();
    try {view.setOnClickListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};
    try {view.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};
    try {view.setOnFocusChangeListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};
    try {view.setOnKeyListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};
    try {view.setOnLongClickListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};
    try {view.setOnClickListener(null);} catch (Throwable mayHappen) {};

    if (view.getBackground() != null)
    {
        message = message + ", setBackgroundCallback(null)";
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }

    if (view instanceof ImageView)
    {
        if (((ImageView)view).getDrawable() != null)
        {
            if (((ImageView)view).getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable)
            {
                message = message + ", recycle bitmap";
                ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView)view).getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
            }
            message = message + ", setDrawableCallback(null)";
            ((ImageView)view).getDrawable().setCallback(null);
        }
        message = message + ", setImageBitmap(null), setBackgroundDrawable(null)";
        ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(null);
        ((ImageView) view).setBackgroundDrawable(null);
    }
    Log.i(TAG, message);
}
```

Once all of the ImageViews are unbounded, I then run the garbage collector in the clearScene function.

***EDIT (4/2/13) OK, after some researching and trial and error, I changed up my memory logging.  Here are the relevant methods:

In onResume(), I set a Boolean to true depending on the version of Android (to determine if it uses native or Java memory for Bitmaps), and then I initialize default value of 0 for the old memory values;

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) debugJavaMemory = true;
    else debugNativeMemory = true;
    availableJavaMemoryOld = 0;
    availableNativeMemoryOld = 0;
    dialogDebug();
}
```

This is my logging function.  It logs depending on whether the current version of Android is using native or Java memory to store Bitmaps.

```
private void logMemory(String callingFunction)
{
    if (debugJavaMemory)
    {
        long max = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024;
        long used = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024;
        long available = max - used;
        long change = available - availableJavaMemoryOld;
        if (availableJavaMemoryOld != 0)
            Log.i(TAG_MEMORY, "jMEM M:" + max + ", U:" + used + ", A:" + available + ", C:" + change + ", " + callingFunction);
        availableJavaMemoryOld = available;
    }
    else if (debugNativeMemory)
    {
        long max = Debug.getNativeHeapSize() / 1024;
        long used = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024;
        long available = max - used;
        long change = available - availableNativeMemoryOld;
        if (availableNativeMemoryOld != 0)
            Log.i(TAG_MEMORY, "nMEM M:" + max + ", U:" + used + ", A:" + available + ", C:" + change + ", " + callingFunction);
        availableNativeMemoryOld = available;
    }
}
```

If you look at my log I collect from an emulator running Android 10 (2.3.3), the garbage collector appears to be working perfectly!  The only thing I noticed that was odd, was that the Max Native Memory could increase dynamically!?

Legend: M: (max memory), U: (used memory), A: (available memory), C: (change in available memory), Function that called log function

```
04-03 02:34:20.758: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:18336, U:13287, A:5049, C:-2549, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:0, s:0, id:0
04-03 02:34:21.267: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:21391, A:177, C:-4872, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:0, s:0, id:1
04-03 02:34:35.227: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:13288, A:8280, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:34:35.267: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:5184, A:16384, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:34:35.327: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:4977, A:16591, C:207, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:34:36.067: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:13082, A:8486, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:0, id:0
04-03 02:34:47.177: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:4979, A:16589, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:34:47.277: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:4978, A:16590, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:34:47.997: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:21568, U:13082, A:8486, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:0
04-03 02:34:49.307: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:26224, U:21186, A:5038, C:-3448, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:1
04-03 02:34:50.597: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:34328, U:29290, A:5038, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:2
04-03 02:34:51.839: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:37395, A:5037, C:-1, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:3
04-03 02:35:00.377: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29293, A:13139, C:8102, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-03 02:35:00.387: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21189, A:21243, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:35:00.397: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13085, A:29347, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:35:00.407: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4982, A:37450, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:35:00.449: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:4, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:35:01.217: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:2, id:0
04-03 02:35:23.458: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:35:23.508: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:35:24.777: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:0
04-03 02:35:25.719: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21186, A:21246, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:1
04-03 02:35:26.457: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29291, A:13141, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:2
04-03 02:35:55.008: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:35:55.027: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:35:55.037: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:35:55.077: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:35:55.829: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:4, id:0
04-03 02:35:56.427: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:4, id:1
04-03 02:36:00.257: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:36:00.278: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:00.318: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:01.687: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:5, id:0
04-03 02:36:06.437: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:06.487: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:07.777: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:6, id:0
04-03 02:36:09.297: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:09.337: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:10.727: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:7, id:0
04-03 02:36:20.947: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:20.987: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:22.367: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:0
04-03 02:36:23.317: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:1
04-03 02:36:23.887: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29291, A:13141, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:2
04-03 02:36:26.507: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:36:26.517: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:36:26.527: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:26.577: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:27.797: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:9, id:0
04-03 02:36:29.248: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:29.287: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:1, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:30.547: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:10, id:0
04-03 02:36:32.177: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:32.228: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4978, A:37454, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:33.467: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13082, A:29350, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:0
04-03 02:36:33.977: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:1
04-03 02:36:34.527: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29291, A:13141, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:2
04-03 02:36:35.058: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:37395, A:5037, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:3
04-03 02:36:41.260: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29291, A:13141, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-03 02:36:41.267: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:36:41.278: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:36:41.287: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:36:41.337: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:36:42.618: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:0, id:0
04-03 02:37:00.550: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:37:00.587: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:37:01.817: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:1, id:0
04-03 02:37:03.347: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:37:03.397: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:37:04.607: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:2, id:0
04-03 02:37:05.258: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:2, id:1
04-03 02:37:07.677: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:37:07.687: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:37:07.737: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:37:09.017: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:3, id:0
04-03 02:37:10.327: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:3, id:1
04-03 02:37:13.330: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:37:13.337: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:37:13.387: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:37:14.697: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:0
04-03 02:37:16.037: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21187, A:21245, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:1
04-03 02:37:17.367: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29292, A:13140, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:2
04-03 02:37:19.087: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:37396, A:5036, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:3
04-03 02:37:44.347: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29293, A:13139, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-03 02:37:44.357: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21189, A:21243, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:37:44.367: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13085, A:29347, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:37:44.377: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4981, A:37451, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:37:44.437: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:2, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:37:45.667: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:0
04-03 02:37:46.917: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21188, A:21244, C:-8105, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:1
04-03 02:37:48.167: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29292, A:13140, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:2
04-03 02:37:49.807: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:37396, A:5036, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:3
04-03 02:38:08.239: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:29293, A:13139, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-03 02:38:08.258: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:21189, A:21243, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-03 02:38:08.267: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13086, A:29346, C:8103, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-03 02:38:08.277: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4982, A:37450, C:8104, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-03 02:38:08.317: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:4979, A:37453, C:3, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-03 02:38:09.527: I/MEMORY(1045): nMEM M:42432, U:13083, A:29349, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:6, id:0
```

As mentioned, the memory is cleaned after the ImageView is unbound!

Here is the log I collected from my broken Nexus 7 running Android 17 (4.2).  It's really hard to understand how the memory is being used here.  It's never consistent!  Sometimes the memory isn't allocated when I load the ImageView.  Sometimes the memory is only cleared when I load a new ImageView.

Legend: M: (max memory), U: (used memory), A: (available memory), C: (change in available memory), Function that called log function

```
04-02 22:37:05.866: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:21300, A:44236, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:0, s:0, id:0
04-02 22:37:06.136: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29444, A:36092, C:-8144, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:0, s:0, id:1
04-02 22:37:19.806: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29432, A:36104, C:12, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:37:19.806: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29432, A:36104, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:37:19.836: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29432, A:36104, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:37:20.116: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37536, A:28000, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:0, id:0
04-02 22:37:28.456: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:4, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:37:28.486: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:37:28.756: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:0
04-02 22:37:29.226: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:1
04-02 22:37:29.706: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:2
04-02 22:37:30.156: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53740, A:11796, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:1, id:3
04-02 22:37:38.676: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:8, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-02 22:37:38.676: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-02 22:37:38.676: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:37:38.676: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:37:38.696: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:37:38.966: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:2, id:0
04-02 22:37:48.156: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:37:48.216: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:16200, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:37:48.676: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:0
04-02 22:37:49.256: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:1
04-02 22:37:49.716: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:3, id:2
04-02 22:38:07.426: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:4, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-02 22:38:07.426: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:07.426: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:07.496: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:07.766: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:4, id:0
04-02 22:38:08.096: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53736, A:11800, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:4, id:1
04-02 22:38:10.896: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53736, A:11800, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:10.896: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53736, A:11800, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:10.916: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53736, A:11800, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:11.436: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53736, A:11800, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:5, id:0
04-02 22:38:19.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53732, A:11804, C:4, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:19.386: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:8100, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:19.866: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:6, id:0
04-02 22:38:21.326: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45632, A:19904, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:21.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:21300, A:44236, C:24332, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:21.906: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:7, id:0
04-02 22:38:24.376: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:24.406: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:24.916: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:0
04-02 22:38:25.496: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37548, A:27988, C:-8144, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:1
04-02 22:38:25.796: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:8, id:2
04-02 22:38:28.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-02 22:38:28.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:28.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:28.376: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:28.846: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:9, id:0
04-02 22:38:29.926: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:29.956: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29400, A:36136, C:16252, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:30.416: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29400, A:36136, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:10, id:0
04-02 22:38:31.446: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29400, A:36136, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:31.476: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:21300, A:44236, C:8100, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:31.966: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:0
04-02 22:38:32.226: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37548, A:27988, C:-8144, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:1
04-02 22:38:32.526: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45652, A:19884, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:2
04-02 22:38:32.816: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:1, s:11, id:3
04-02 22:38:34.396: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-02 22:38:34.396: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-02 22:38:34.396: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:34.396: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:34.426: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:34.886: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:0, id:0
04-02 22:38:35.776: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53756, A:11780, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:35.816: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:21300, A:44236, C:32456, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:36.256: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:1, id:0
04-02 22:38:36.976: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:37.006: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:37.436: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:29404, A:36132, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:2, id:0
04-02 22:38:37.816: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37548, A:27988, C:-8144, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:2, id:1
04-02 22:38:44.986: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:16, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:44.986: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:45.016: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:45.496: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:37532, A:28004, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:3, id:0
04-02 22:38:45.996: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:3, id:1
04-02 22:38:48.306: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:48.306: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:48.336: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:48.846: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:0
04-02 22:38:49.326: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:45636, A:19900, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:1
04-02 22:38:49.856: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:53740, A:11796, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:2
04-02 22:38:50.386: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61844, A:3692, C:-8104, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:4, id:3
04-02 22:38:59.486: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:12, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:3
04-02 22:38:59.486: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:2
04-02 22:38:59.486: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:1
04-02 22:38:59.486: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, clearScene, CLEARED VIEW id:0
04-02 22:38:59.516: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, clearScene, AFTER TRASH COLLECTOR
04-02 22:38:59.936: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:0
04-02 22:39:00.356: I/MEMORY(15827): jMEM M:65536, U:61832, A:3704, C:0, loadScene, ADDED IMAGE b:2, s:5, id:1
```

I've been through the "Displaying Bitmaps Effectively" training at
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

I've also been through the following stackoverflow questions:
[Recycle ImageView's Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009086/recycle-imageviews-bitmap)
[ImageView: automatically recycle bitmap if ImageView is not visible (within ScrollView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349958/imageview-automatically-recycle-bitmap-if-imageview-is-not-visible-within-scro)
[android - out of memory exception when creating bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697760/android-out-of-memory-exception-when-creating-bitmap)
[Bitmap decodeStream OutOfMemory Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624086/bitmap-decodestream-outofmemory-exception)
[Detect application heap size in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android)
[android createBitmap OOM when ((freeMemory > bitmapSize) && (nativeFreeHeap < bitmap size))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541624/android-createbitmap-oom-when-freememory-bitmapsize-nativefreeheap-bi)
[android 495KB image taking 10MB of Heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357483/android-495kb-image-taking-10mb-of-heap-size)
[Android ImageView setImageBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938785/android-imageview-setimagebitmap)
[Android Memory Leak solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815880/android-memory-leak-solution)
[Android custom view Bitmap memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197794/android-custom-view-bitmap-memory-leak)

And many many more articles across the web!

To clarify, this only seems to happen in my Nexus 7.  I haven't experienced the issue on my emulator or my Galaxy Nexus.  I think this may be due to the fact that I am scaling the images.

Please help me detect where the memory leak is!

***EDIT (4/2/13) Please help me identify why the logs from an emulator running Android 10 (2.3.3) show the system allocating memory and the garbage then clearing in exactly like it should, and the logs from my Nexus 7 running Android 17 (4.2) show the system allocating memory and the garbage collector clearing memory apparently at random?

Comment: +1 for the research.But,is this exception only showing up on emulator or does it show on devices too?

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question, I am only experiencing the problem on my Nexus 7.  My galaxy nexus and emulator don't seem to have the problem.  I think it's because I'm scaling the images.

Comment: A weak reference may be ineffective on a bitmap because a bitmap looks small for the gc. (And in general one should never `doAnything(bmp.get())` for the reason that the WeakReference may get freed.)

Comment: Try to find a way to print out objects in the heap. At least, their classes and sizes.

Comment: Any success? It would be interesting to hear how this got resolved.

Comment: All, please check the edit.  I added new logs and I am baffled as to why it works perfectly on Gingerbread and not on Jelly Bean... any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to determine why memory allocation and collection is different among the different platforms, but I was able to mitigate the problem and prevent my application from crashing on any platform by scaling the images down to fit available memory.

This first function determines where the Bitmap memory is being stored (native or Java), and then calculates the remaining available memory (in KB).

```
private long calcAvailableMemory()
{
    long value = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    String type = "";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    {
        value = value / 1024) - (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024);
        type = "JAVA";
    }
    else
    {
        value = value / 1024) - (Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024);
        type = "NATIVE";
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "calcAvailableMemory, size = " + value + ", type = " + type);
    return value;
}
```

This second function creates an ImageView to attach to the Layout.  The Show object contains different variables I need to initialize the ImageView such as dimensions and filepath etc.  The long maxImageMemory is derived from the first function, and is then divided by the number of views I'm attaching to the layout giving the me maximum amount of memory to allocate each Bitmap.

```
private ImageView newImage(Show show, long maxImageMemory)
{
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    String filePath = comin.generateFilePath(show);
    Bitmap bmp = scaleBitmap(filePath, maxImageMemory);
    Log.i(TAG, "newImage, id:" + show.id + ", file:" + filePath + ", x:" + bmp.getWidth() + ", y:" + bmp.getHeight());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setId(show.id);

    //set visibility
    if (show.visible)
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //set dimensions
    int width = (app.getWidth() * show.dimX) / 100;
    int height = (app.getHeight() * show.dimY) / 100;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
    iv.setLayoutParams(rlp);

    return iv;
}
```

This third function scales the Bitmap that will be loaded into the ImageView being created in function 2.  The while loop is the important part, that is where I increase the sample size until the needed memory for the bitmap is less than the maximum memory available.

```
private Bitmap scaleBitmap(String path, long maxImageMemory)
{
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    int sample = 1;
    //Scale image to screen resolution
    if (options.outHeight > app.getHeight() || options.outWidth > app.getWidth())
    {
        int heightRatio = Math.round((float) options.outHeight / (float) app.getHeight());
        int widthRatio = Math.round((float) options.outWidth / (float) app.getWidth());
        sample = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    //Scale image to stay within memory limitations
    while (calcBitmapSize(options.outWidth, options.outHeight, sample) > maxImageMemory)
    {
        sample++;
    }

    options.inSampleSize = sample;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    Log.i(TAG, "scaleBitmap, scaleSample = " + sample);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

This fourth function calculates the amount of memory required by the Bitmap depending on the original resolution, as well as the proposed sample size.

```
private long calcBitmapSize(int width, int height, int sample)
{
    long value = ((width/sample) * (height/sample) * 4) / 1024;
    Log.i(TAG, "calcBitmapSize, size = " + value);
    return value;
}
```

Lastly, I developed this function to assist in troubleshooting all of these memory problems.  It logs memory utilization depending on which version of Android you are running.

```
private void logMemory(String callingFunction)
{
    long max = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024;

    if (debugJavaMemory)
    {
        long used = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024;
        long available = max - used;
        long change = available - availableJavaMemoryOld;
        if (availableJavaMemoryOld != 0)
            Log.i(TAG_MEMORY, "jMEM M:" + max + ", U:" + used + ", A:" + available + ", C:" + change + ", " + callingFunction);
        availableJavaMemoryOld = available;
    }
    else if (debugNativeMemory)
    {
        long used = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() / 1024;
        long available = max - used;
        long change = available - availableNativeMemoryOld;
        if (availableNativeMemoryOld != 0)
            Log.i(TAG_MEMORY, "nMEM M:" + max + ", U:" + used + ", A:" + available + ", C:" + change + ", " + callingFunction);
        availableNativeMemoryOld = available;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem couple of months ago,
try this,may help:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 8;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I currently have a dynamic down sampling function which I made courtesy of the Android Training at http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html  The function ends up returning a sampleSize value of 1, since the resolution matches the image.  Each image appears to use around 8MB of memory (as seen in the logs).  If one scene only has 4 images it would be a grand total of 32MB, or about half of the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

This link may help you http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html 
This problem also arises when the drawable is not available in the **drawable-xhdpi** folder for the large 720x1280 mobiles. Please cross check it that the drawables you are using are in the correct drawable folder.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I have already been through that training.  The app is designed to load the images from the SD card.  Please explain your reasoning that the folder your store your image in would help decrease memory utilization or release the memory when needed.

Comment: May this answer will solve your query. This problem i have faced and solved it in this way and now it is working properly.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394329/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-appears-after-sherlockactionbar-was-added/15395218#15395218